# Bootstrap 4 navbar lost it's background during coding

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm new to Boostrap, and in an attempt to make a navbar more responsive for all screens and add some effects somewhere along the way my navbar lost its background color.
I've tried explicitly taking the navbar-light class and changed it's colour, but it doesn't seem to work.

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>
      Navbar
    </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header_area">
      <div class="main_menu">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
          <div class="container box_1620">
            <a class="navbar-brand logo_h" href="index.html"><h2>Brand</h2></a>
            <button
              class="navbar-toggler"
              type="button"
              data-toggle="collapse"
              data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
              aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
              aria-expanded="false"
              aria-label="Toggle navigation"
            >
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div
              class="collapse navbar-collapse offset"
              id="navbarSupportedContent"
            >
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav menu_nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="pricing.html">Pricing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
.header_area {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  border-width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.4s, all 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition: background 0.4s, all 0.3s linear;
  transition: background 0.4s, all 0.3s linear;
}

.header_area .navbar {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  border-width: 0px;
}

.header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item {
  margin-right: 45px;
}

.header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  font: 500 12px/100px "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #222222;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item .nav-link:after {
  display: none;
}

.header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item:hover .nav-link,
.header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item.active .nav-link {
  color: #ff2f92;
}

.header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item.submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item.submenu ul {
  border: none;
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin: 0px;
  background: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item.submenu ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 120%;
    left: 0px;
    min-width: 200px;
    text-align: left;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in;
    display: block;
    border: none;
    padding: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
  }
}

.header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item.submenu ul:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #eeeeee transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  right: 24px;
  top: 45px;
  z-index: 3;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 400ms linear;
  transition: all 400ms linear;
}

.header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item.submenu ul .nav-item {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  margin-right: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
  margin-left: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s linear;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
}

.header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item.submenu ul .nav-item .nav-link {
  line-height: 45px;
  color: #222222;
  padding: 0px 30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 150ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 150ms linear;
  transition: all 150ms linear;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item.submenu ul .nav-item:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item.submenu ul .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
  background: #ff2f92;
  color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item.submenu:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 100%;
  }
}

.header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item.submenu:hover ul .nav-item {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.header_area + section,
.header_area + row,
.header_area + div {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.header_area.navbar_fixed .main_menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: -70px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(70px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(70px);
  transform: translateY(70px);
  -webkit-transition: background 500ms ease, -webkit-transform 500ms ease;
  transition: background 500ms ease, -webkit-transform 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: transform 500ms ease, background 500ms ease;
  transition: transform 500ms ease, background 500ms ease;
  transition: transform 500ms ease, background 500ms ease,
    -webkit-transform 500ms ease;
  -webkit-transition: transform 500ms ease, background 500ms ease;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

I want to know why this happened, where I went wrong and a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
```

In bootstrap 4 we use `bg-light` instead of `navbar-light`  like below...

If you want another colors, check the documentation here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#color-schemes

```css
.header_area {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  border-width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.4s, all 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition: background 0.4s, all 0.3s linear;
  transition: background 0.4s, all 0.3s linear;
}

.header_area .navbar {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  border-width: 0px;
}

.header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item {
  margin-right: 45px;
}

.header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #222222;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item .nav-link:after {
  display: none;
}

.header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item:hover .nav-link,
.header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item.active .nav-link {
  color: #ff2f92;
}

.header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item.submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item.submenu ul {
  border: none;
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin: 0px;
  background: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item.submenu ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 120%;
    left: 0px;
    min-width: 200px;
    text-align: left;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in;
    display: block;
    border: none;
    padding: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
  }
}

.header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item.submenu ul:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #eeeeee transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  right: 24px;
  top: 45px;
  z-index: 3;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 400ms linear;
  transition: all 400ms linear;
}

.header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item.submenu ul .nav-item {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  margin-right: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
  margin-left: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s linear;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
}

.header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item.submenu ul .nav-item .nav-link {
  line-height: 45px;
  color: #222222;
  padding: 0px 30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 150ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 150ms linear;
  transition: all 150ms linear;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item.submenu ul .nav-item:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item.submenu ul .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
  background: #ff2f92;
  color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item.submenu:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 100%;
  }
}

.header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item.submenu:hover ul .nav-item {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.header_area + section,
.header_area + row,
.header_area + div {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.header_area.navbar_fixed .main_menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: -70px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(70px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(70px);
  transform: translateY(70px);
  -webkit-transition: background 500ms ease, -webkit-transform 500ms ease;
  transition: background 500ms ease, -webkit-transform 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: transform 500ms ease, background 500ms ease;
  transition: transform 500ms ease, background 500ms ease;
  transition: transform 500ms ease, background 500ms ease,
    -webkit-transform 500ms ease;
  -webkit-transition: transform 500ms ease, background 500ms ease;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>
      Navbar
    </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header_area">
      <div class="main_menu">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
          <div class="container box_1620">
            <a class="navbar-brand logo_h" href="index.html"><h2>Brand</h2></a>
            <button
              class="navbar-toggler"
              type="button"
              data-toggle="collapse"
              data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
              aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
              aria-expanded="false"
              aria-label="Toggle navigation"
            >
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div
              class="collapse navbar-collapse offset"
              id="navbarSupportedContent"
            >
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav menu_nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="pricing.html">Pricing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem about the huge navbar is here:

```
.header_area .navbar .nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  font: 500 12px/100px "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #222222;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

What's doing that is the line:

```
font: 500 12px/100px "Roboto", sans-serif;
```

You have to put a smaller font, or just delete it and it'll do the trick!

Comment: Damn, I wasted hours trying to figure this out! Also, Miguel could you tell me why my navbar has a big height? like it's fat, what property have I used to do so?

Comment: Next time, you should really just see the documentation first, and you'll save yourself a couple of hours :p If i was able to help you, mark as correct answer so that we can help other people.

Comment: I'll check it out, wait please.

Comment: Yeah, whenever i add a button, the border of the button stretches to the 2 sides of the navbar because of this thickness problem

Comment: I found your problem. I'll update the answer above.